# How to computer the keyname under name2sid?

Tags: windows

Quick question:

Does someone knows how are computed the keynames under Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IdentityStore\LogonCache\B16898C6-A148-4967-9171-64D755DA8520\Name2Sid ?

example Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IdentityStore\LogonCache\B16898C6-A148-4967-9171-64D755DA8520\Name2Sid\156f1310d4be533e80fa9161b17c40ac183a5451f8c67d9c9f828531c96db3cf

156f1310d4be533e80fa9161b17c40ac183a5451f8c67d9c9f828531c96db3cf is not random. If I login on 2 computers, the value is the same. I tried to derive it from my SID or objectID but didn't found how it's computed. ( and 2 different users have different keyname)

Thanks in advance.